# mysql select statement IN

Tags: mysql

I am having two table

Table 1 having a field

| id | book_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |

Table 2 have all the book Ids

```
select * 
from table 2 
where book_id in (select book_ids from table 1 where id=1) ;
```

this statement not returning all the book ids from table 2 having id 1,2,3

Can anyone help

Comment: Before doing anything else please read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: may be it is not the right way to store data, Still is there any solution available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [FIND_IN_SET() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select * 
from table 2 
where FIND_IN_SET(book_id, (select book_ids from table 1 where id=1)) > 0;
```

Read the documentation I linked to for details on how that function works.

But only do this if your table remains small. Using this function spoils any opportunity to optimize the query with an index, so the larger your table gets, the performance will grow worse and worse.

Also FIND_IN_SET() doesn't work the way you expect if there are spaces in your comma-separated list.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(book_id, (select book_ids from table1 where id = 1)) ; 


This is working all fine
Thanks a lot Bill Karwin

Answer (score 0):

try to store table1 values in rows of table not in a same field.
and then your SELECT IN works.